# R: writing outputfiles with specific combinations of columns, using a (nested) loop

Tags: r, loops

I have the following data frame:

```
IID.m IID.f score.m measure.m health.m score.f measure.f health.f 
1 2 120 80 8 131 82 5
3 4 121 83 9 119 80 7
5 6 133 78 5 121 87 9
7 8 126 87 8 120 83 4
```

So two IDs (let's say, father=IID.m and mother=IID.f) and three variables that belong to the first ID (score.m, measure.m, and health.m) and the same three after that belonging to the second ID (score.f, measure.f, and health.f).

I need to make the following output files that consist of four columns:

File 1:

```
score.m health.f health.m score.f
```

File 2:

```
measure.m health.f health.m measure.f
```

File 3:

```
measure.m score.f score.m measure.f
```

In other words: two out of the three variables for the father and mother, in the order of "variable 1 of the father", "variable 2 of the mother", "variable 2 of the father", "variable 1 of the mother". These need to be separate tab-delimited output files for all combinations of variables.

In this case this would mean only three different output files, because there are only three different combinations (score+health, measure+health, measure+score). In reality I have far more variables, so much more possible combinations, which is why I suspect I need a for-loop (or a for loop within a for loop?). How do I do this within R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider running `combn` to get all combinations of the *score*, *measure*, and *health* column indices. Then run that return list in `lapply` to build subsetted dataframes. However, you do not want all combinations but only where pairings match between *f* and *m*, so run a `Filter` on list of dataframe and specifically run another `combn` to build variable pairings for `grep` calls.

**Data**

```
txt = 'IID.m IID.f score.m measure.m health.m score.f measure.f health.f 
1 2 120 80 8 131 82 5
3 4 121 83 9 119 80 7
5 6 133 78 5 121 87 9
7 8 126 87 8 120 83 4'

df <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
```

**Dataframe List Build**

```
value_combos <- combn(3:ncol(df), 4, simplify = FALSE)

df_list <- lapply(value_combos, function(i) df[, i])

col_pairs <- lapply(combn(unique(gsub("\\.m|\\.f", "", names(df)[-2:-1])), 2, simplify = FALSE),
                    function(i) paste(i, collapse="|"))
col_pairs
# [[1]]
# [1] "score|measure"

# [[2]]
# [1] "score|health"

# [[3]]
# [1] "measure|health"

sub_df_list <-lapply(col_pairs, function(x) 
  Filter(function(d) length(grep(x, names(d))) == 4 , df_list)[[1]])

sub_df_list
# [[1]]
#   score.m measure.m score.f measure.f
# 1     120        80     131        82
# 2     121        83     119        80
# 3     133        78     121        87
# 4     126        87     120        83

# [[2]]
#   score.m health.m score.f health.f
# 1     120        8     131        5
# 2     121        9     119        7
# 3     133        5     121        9
# 4     126        8     120        4

# [[3]]
#   measure.m health.m measure.f health.f
# 1        80        8        82        5
# 2        83        9        80        7
# 3        78        5        87        9
# 4        87        8        83        4

# OUTPUT TAB-DELIMITED FILES FROM LIST
lapply(seq_along(sub_df_list), function(i) 
          write.table(sub_df_list[[i]], file = paste0("Output", i, ".txt"), sep="\t"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have an alternative for your filter command, in which I don't have to spell out the combinations? There are many more in my actual dataset...

Comment: See update running another `combn` for all unique variable pairings.